# CUDA surfaces vs textures

Tags: memory, cuda

What is the difference between a surface and texture object in CUDA? When should I use one or the other?

As far as I can tell from the developer documentation, they are exactly the same. Both appear to be CUDA arrays that use special texture memory. The only difference seems to be the API methods that access the memory.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Textures](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#texture-memory) are read-only, [surfaces](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#surface-memory) are writable and readable. The surface API was introduced later to accomodate for this difference.

Use textures for data that your kernels read only, surfaces if they also write to it.

Comment: It's also worth noting that textures support hardware filtering / interpolation, whereas surfaces do not.

Comment: @BenjaminBray If surfaces do not support HW filtering / interpolation, when to use surfaces vs regular arrays?

Comment: @user2052436 Well surfaces can be 2D, 3D, cubemaps, etc which makes indexing into them easier. Any sort of texutre-like thing on the GPU can benefit from various hardware differences between textures and arrays such as the way they are cached or specific texture encodings, though I am not sure how much of that CUDA actually supports (it is pretty barebones in terms of texture formats).